# jquery validate with multiple rules

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

How to validate a email address field with three rules with three customized messages in the div container. 
ie.

```
rules: {
    email: {
        validationRule: true,
        email: true,
        remote: '/ajax/emailDuplicationCheck.php'
       }
     }
```

if first one false message should be "validation rule failed"

if second one false(fail) "enter email address"

if third(remote) failed. message should be "Account already exist in database".

I can added one message for all rules but i want to customize the message with respect to the rules.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#myForm").validate({ // Replace #myForm with the ID of your form
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "/ajax/emailDuplicationCheck.php",
                type: "post",
                data: { email: function() {
                    return $("#email").val(); // Add #email ID to your email field
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: 'Email address is required',
            email: 'Please enter a valid email address',
            remote: 'This email address has already been used'
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error) {
        $("#response").html(error);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: No. it is not working. it is only displaying the message in email: 'enter email address'. As I mentioned. I want to display msg in div container?

Comment: The syntax is correct and that's the way it's supposed to be done, so the problem must be somewhere else. `validationRule` looks like a custom validation method. What exactly is it supposed to be doing ? Can you please edit your question and add the code for that method as well ?

Comment: validationRule method doing nothing. it is just return true. well if i remove that line. even than it is not working with two rules. and how can I display it in Divcontainer of id #response. I want to display the message in div container

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Also please note that in order to get the remote validation working, your `emailDuplicationCheck.php` file should listen for `$_POST['email']` and ONLY output `false` if the email is used, or `true` if the email is NOT used.

Comment: errorPlacement is the part which i was missing :) it works. thanks for help

Comment: Thanks guys, this helped me fix a similar problem.

Comment: what is emailDuplicationCheck.php supoused to return? true or false?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet as I said in my second comment above, it should return `true` if the email is not used or `false` if the email is already in use.

Comment: @Valentin Flachsel, Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086843/how-can-i-make-two-message-in-password-confirmation-in-jquery-validate

Answer (score 5):

You can use custom validation rules along with your own custom messages for each rule.

For simplicity, here's an example of how to validate a 'username' input with three custom methods for validation (each with its' own error message):

```
// Add three custom methods first:

$.validator.addMethod("nameCustom", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z ]+/.test(value);
}, 'Please use english letters only.');

$.validator.addMethod("noSpaceStart", function(value, element) { 
    return value.indexOf(" ") != 0; 
}, "Name cannot start with a space");

$.validator.addMethod("noSpaceEnd", function(value, element) { 
    return value.lastIndexOf(" ") != value.length - 1; 
}, "Name cannot end with a space");

$('#form_to_validate').validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            // Add the custom validation methods to the username input
            noSpaceStart: true,
            noSpaceEnd: true,
            nameCustom: true,
            // required and maxlength are built-in methods in the plugin and are ready to be used
            required: true,
            maxlength: 50
        }
    }
});
```