# How can I make two message in password confirmation in jQuery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My html code like this :

```
<form class="validatedForm" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="password" id="password" />
        <input name="password_confirmation" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<button>Validate</button>
```

My javascript code to validate with jquery validate like this :

```
jQuery('.validatedForm').validate({
    rules: {
        "password": {
            minlength: 6
        },
        "password_confirmation": {
            minlength: 6,
            equalTo : "#password"
        }
    },
      messages: {
            "password": 'Please enter a password, minimal 6 characters',
            "password_confirmation": 'Please confirm your password'
    },
});
```

Demo and full code like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/fEZFB/609/

If user input password : `abcdef`, then click button validate, there exist messsage : "Please confirm your password"

If user input password confirmation : `ghijkl`, there exist message : "Please confirm your password"

I want to change the message if user input password confirmation not same

The message like this : "confirm your password is not the same"

So there exist two message :

1. If user not input password confirmation, the message : "Please confirm your password"
2. If user input password confirmation, but not same with password, the message : "confirm your password is not the same"

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will cover what you're looking for.  You aren't limited to one message per input - you can set one for each rule on each input.  I added a break in your HTML to make it more readable.

```
<form class="validatedForm" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="password" id="password" /><br/>
        <input name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<button>Validate</button>
```

Updated script:

```
jQuery('.validatedForm').validate({
    rules: {
        "password": {
            minlength: 6,
            required: true
        },
        "password_confirmation": {
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    },
      messages: {
            "password": {
            minLength: "Password must be at least 6 charachters",
            required: "Password is required."
        },
            "password_confirmation": {
            equalTo: "The password and confimation fields don't match"
        }
    },
});

$('button').click(function () {
    console.log($('.validatedForm').valid());
});
```

I added a required rule to the password so clicking validate with a blank form generates a message.  I removed the minlength on the confirmation- it only needs to be equal to the password, and it has a minlength.  Too short of a password has its own message, and when the password is long enough you'll get a different message when the confirmation field is empty or otherwise not equal to the password.  You can see it in the fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/fEZFB/609/

Comment: password and password_confirmation is not required

Comment: Remove the required rule and message?

Comment: It seems you do not understand what I mean. But it's okay. I've found the answer